# How to get count(max(marks)) , marks, subject from info_table group by subject , marks;

Tags: mysql, hive

I need a query which can display count of max marks score in each subject.
say 3 students scored 98 in science by output needs to be

```
count marks subject
3      98    Maths
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the max mark for each subject and use this result set as a sub-query and use `EXISTS` to find the count from the table which having the max mark.

**Query**

```
select `subject`, 
count(*) as `count`, 
max(`marks`) as `marks`
from `student` t1
where exists(
  select 1 from (
    select `subject`,
    max(`marks`) as `max_marks`
    from `student`
    group by `subject`
  ) t2
  where t1.`subject` = t2.`subject`
  and t1.`marks` = t2.`max_marks`
)
group by `subject`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SQL below if your question is on Hive

v_max_marks gets the max mark for each subject. This view is then joined to the main table to get the student count.

```
WITH v_max_marks
AS
(SELECT subject, MAX(marks) AS marks
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY subject)
SELECT my_table.subject, 
       my_table.marks, 
       COUNT(*) AS student_count
  FROM my_table JOIN v_max_marks 
                  ON (my_table.subject = v_max_marks.subject AND 
                      my_table.marks = v_max_marks.marks)
 GROUP BY my_table.subject, 
          my_table.marks;
```